# Cannot read property 'getInstance' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

When trying to authorize an org/ trying to deploying source to org / retrieve the source from an org i'm getting below error. kindly help me to resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating sfdx? Run `sfdx update` from command prompt or terminal, and try again.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue in the past. Reinstalling the SFDX CLI has resolved the issue for me

SFDX CLI installation link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I tried both updating CLI using SFDX update command and reinstalling salesforce CLI  in my machine. Both workarounds don't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

run the command **sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx**  in cmd prompt terminal,this will resolve your issue

Comment: This helped but can you explain what's the possible cause please ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it following the steps of this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm

Hope this solve your problem.

P.D: The steps to solve it:
Select Start > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features.

Select SFDX CLI, and click Uninstall.

Inside your home directory, delete the .config\sfdx directory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137259)

Comment: Sorry, I edit my answer. Thanks for the advice :D

Comment: Thanks to everyone.By executing sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx  in cmd prompt resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1- Uninstall Salesforce CLI

2- Go to windows explorer and use this path "%LOCALAPPDATA%\sfdx"

3- Delete all the files from there

4- Reinstall Salesforce CLI